# Would I need to cross compile Python to ARM?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, ctype

I have Python code that works on a 32bit intel machine running Ubuntu, and I need to run this code on Raspberry Pi. Would I need some sort of cross compiling? I have 32bit .so files included in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is an interpreted bytecode language, so the actual python code does *not* need to be cross compiled in any way;

Your shared libraries, files ending in `.so` are *not* python, however.  You will need to obtain versions of those compiled for the correct architecture.  It might well be that those are ordinary C extensions for python, which can be built via setuptools or other means, which works equally well on ARM as it does on i386.